# Skyline select wrong zone

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, 3d-analyst

I need to make skyline for my DEM with buildings on it. The height of building is height of DEM + height of building.

The problem that tool select me improbable zone:

[image]

It's not possible that part of buildings (polygon have fixed height) are visiable and part of not.

ArcGIS 10.4.1 
Radius 100 meters

I am using skyline tool.

Comment: Which version are you using? What is the sampling distance? What is the DEM spacing (especially relative to the building dimensions). Did you set the building height to be a basic add to the DEM? If so, the top of the building has the same profile as the DEM (just higher), which probably isn't true.

Comment: "What is the sampling distance? What is the DEM spacing (especially relative to the building dimensions)" Sorry I do not know where to check it.

I created building height with `Add Surface Information` and then added to it height of buildings from their metadata. If it's wrong - why? By the logic it's simply add Z_MEAN (or any other) value from surface to polygon

Comment: Right-click the raster and select properties.  I think BradHards is correct, there looks to be a serious mismatch between your buildings and the raster.    I also seriously doubt your 100m radius based on the width of the building at the top.  Finally, your DEM appears to have trees in it (ie not bare earth, so you can't place buildings on top of it as they will then sit on top of trees).  I think you need to give us a lot more information before you can be sure of getting a sensible result from this calculation.

Comment: Do a sanity check of your DEM + building. What is the height of the building at each point? Its probably not the skyline tool, but rather the data you are feeding it.